# Generate custom build name with webpack and VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I want to generate custom name for my build file.

I have a vueJS 2 project, and according to [this doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) i should create a `vue-config.js` file root of my project.
This is what i did with this content according to [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) :

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
  },
};
```

but when i build this does not change the name i still have this as a result :

[image]

What did i missed ? thanks in advance to the community

Comment: The name of the file is `vue.config.js`

Comment: well that was quick, worked ! thanks @roliroli